# Apple M1/M2 chips for acoustic deep learning

Tags: analysis, pam, machine-learning, cnn, deep-learning

I’ve  been reading that both Tensorflow and Pytorch deep learning frameworks are now supported by Apple M1/M2 chips. This means that a deep learning acoustic species classifier should run an order of magnitude faster on these chips than on an Intel or AMD PC (without an Nvidea graphics card). Has anyone tried to use these Apple chips in acoustics yet and, if so, were you able to measure performance increase?

EDIT. Although this question may seem general, there are nuances applying deep learning models to acoustics. For example, there is a whole acoustic processing chain to convert a waveform to an image (usually) which can involve multiple signal processing techniques such as filter or FFT calculations which may or may not be optimised on different chips. In addition, the community often use frameworks such as Ketos or AnimalSpot for developing models which may perform differently depending on whether the developer has optomised for different types of processor. The question is therefore asked in a bioacoustics context and answers ideally will also be focussed on performance increases in bioacoustics applications.

Comment: I still can't get Tensorflow or Keras to load on my M1 Macbook after many attempts and head-banging-against-wall. Love that the error message I get literally says "illegal hardware"... Pytorch seems to load easier.

Do you have links/code that have worked for you to load Tensorflow on M1 chips?

Comment: Also, I'll be able to answer this in about 3 weeks as I will be doing just that (ML models for automatic species detection from PAM data) for the CV4Ecology summer school at CalTech.

Comment: How about this. Seems like it takes a bit to get working but it should be possible to run a tensorflow model on the AI portion of the chip. https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out and see if that works for me. Such a frustrating problem!

Comment: Not doing this as an answer per se but this is a thought: it'd be useful to start collecting benchmarks of various key acoustic processes for posterity: I'm doing X process on Y dataset with Z hardware and it took N hours

Comment: @dtsavage - that is a good idea - just need to agree on what the benchmark is so folk can submit results.

Comment: Hi @JamieMacaulay - what makes this a *bioacoustics* question? Why do you feel bioacoustic deep learning would be different from other deep learning, when it comes to these chips? I am strongly tempted to say this question is off-topic...

Comment: @DanStowell, I would strongly disagree that this question is not appropriate for bioacoustics stack exchange. For a start, just because a question is applicable to other fields does not mean it is not suitable for the forum. Deep learning is being widely used in the field and it is appropriate to ask about hardware because 1) there me be nuances specifically for acoustics and 2) it can be more accessible to answer questions in an acoustics context.  Are we going to say questions about stats, moorings, signal processing etc are not appropriate because they can be used in different areas?

Comment: @JamieMacaulay For your point 1 (" there me be nuances specifically for acoustics"), what would be the nuances? Maybe you should clarify this in your question.  If you remove all the words "acoustics" in your question, does it change anything? I have the impression that it doesnt.

Comment: @JamieMacaulay For your point 2 ("it can be more accessible to answer questions in an acoustics context."), then what about if somebody asks a question about a problem with their car engine because they need to go to the field to measure animal sounds? I struggle to see a fundamental difference between the car engine and the computer engine. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @JamieMacaulay Finally, is there any other SE site that could answer this question better? If not, it is a good argument to keep it here, but this should be said in the question to my opinion to avoid any question closure. I quickly checked on https://stackexchange.com/sites,  I found this [hardware SE site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but not sure if it is appropriate

Comment: I think context is important here. Jamie is asking for performance recommendations for a deep learning program directed for bioacoustics. I don't think the car engine comparison is fair. Our field is young and many people are still building the tools needed to conduct research. Open discussions about best methods are important for global accessibility.

Comment: @etgriffiths What I mean is: If the deep learning program would be for another application which requires as much "power" than the acoustic one, would it change anything?

Comment: @Noil - 1) Nuances in acoustics - there's different types of signal processing to be done before a waveform is converted into (usually) an image.  Processes like calculating an FFT could be slower/faster. Are frameworks like Ketos or AnimalSpot compatible? 2) Obviously there is a line but I don't think this crosses it - would you close a stats question on dolphin distribution because it's based on wider distance sampling or modelling methods? 3) There are certainly other sites but none that would answer in the context of bio-acoustics.

Comment: @Noil, no, it wouldn't. However, I think my point still stands. Even if some of the questions on this site have other applications, the intent behind the question is to improve bioacoustic analysis techniques. I think it falls under the bioacoustics umbrella because of that.  We have already had a bunch of statistics questions, which I think belong here with the right framing, because figuring out what statistical tests and survey design are appropriate for bioacoustic research can be difficult.

Comment: This is one of the reasons WHY we wanted a bioacoustics SE. Because there are so many different fields that feed into what we do, and it's truely hard to keep track of them, or be knowledgeable in all of them.

Comment: If the performance of the chip is dependent of the type of computation (e.g. FFT), then I agree with both of you; Jamie's comment tends to say so, then maybe this could be added after the question as a note (by assuming that the reader does not know about chips)? This would help people who review the questions. Otherwise, if it is "just" a question of chip power, independently of any specific sound processing, I find it rather too general, even in the context of the multidisciplinary field of bioacoustics.

Comment: @Noil - it may be the case performance is different but regardless, I still believe this is an appropriate question. We should, however, move this discussion to Meta. Here is the link - https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/debate-on-whether-a-haqrdware-question-is-appropriate-for-bioacoustics

Comment: @JamieMacaulay could you edit your question to emphasise what makes it bioacoustics-specific? You seem to have an idea about FFT speed also having some relation with the Apple chips (unless I'm mistaken), which wasn't in your original question.

Comment: @DanStowell. I have edited the question hopefully with a better explanation of why this relates to bioacoustics. If you have other suggestions I am happy to edit it further.

Comment: IMHO, a question on a processor (Here M1/M2) could per se be off-topic. I could ask the same question about using an ARM Cortex M7 MCU for bioacoustics. The default answer is "Yes, it depends on how much you wanted to do". If there exist specific hardware for collecting bioacoustic data, then one could allow questions on this device using a particular processor. For most recorders the processor is not emphasized, as it is only a vehicle for recording. If we are going to implement smart devices for bio-acoustic research with build-in processing then IMO the type of processor can matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible. We are successfully running training and inference of deep learning models on Apple Silicon M1/M2 chips using OpenSoundscape (opensoundscape.org) which uses PyTorch under the hood.

Currently, not all operations are supported by these chips (`mps`) - in particular, FFT is not yet supported (follow https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/78044). However, you can still take advantage of GPU speedups in the forward and backward passes of the CNN, while using parallelized CPUs for preprocessing of samples (including fft during spectrogram generation). We've seen great performance so far using M1 chips for training CNNs. (I don't have any head-to-head tests to share at the moment).

To use mps in OpenSoundscape's CNN class, set the object's .device to `torch.device('mps')`. For example:

```
import torch
from opensoundscape import CNN

cnn = CNN('resnet18',classes=['a','b','c'],sample_duration=3.0)

if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
    cnn.device = torch.device("mps")
```

You can also use `mps` with pytorch directly (check out the source code of OpenSoundscape's CNN class and  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/mps.html#mps-backend)

(in case it matters - I'm a developer of OpenSoundscape)